# PLSQL Oracle10 Dialect mimic UPSERT functionality using trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-trigger, insert-update

I have a table with a primary key id, first name, last name, and a unique company id.

```
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE"(
  "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
  "LASNT_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
  "COMPANY_ID" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE))
CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
CONSTRAINT "UNIQUE_COMPANY_ID" UNIQUE ("COMPANY_ID")
```

I have a batch job that checks for new hires and name changes and runs an insert statement

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COMPANY_ID)
VALUES("NEW EMPLOYEE FIRST NAME","NEW EMPLOYEE LAST NAME", "NEW EMPLOYEE 123")
```

If there was an employee that changed their name, an oracle exception will be thrown.

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (UNIQUE_COMPANY_ID) violated
```

I want to update when this exception would be thrown instead of attempting to insert the value. Should I use a trigger for this? Would it look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_TO_UPDATE
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   NULL;
EXCEPTION
   UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET
       FIRST_NAME = :NEW.FIRST_NAME,
       LAST_NAME = :NEW.LAST_NAME
END;
```

Where I do not do anything in the begin block and catch the exception. I am guessing that since there is nothing to run in the begin block it will run the insert, then if there is an employee with the same EMPLOYEE_ID it catches the exception thrown previously. Should I do the check if there is a row in the begin block like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_TO_UPDATE
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    results_found NUMBER(1,0)
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO results_found
   FROM EMPLOYEE
   AND COMPANY_ID = :NEW.COMPANY_ID;
   IF results_found = 0 THEN
       INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COMPANY_ID)
       VALUES(:NEW.FIRST_NAME,:NEW.LAST_NAME)
   END IF;
   END;

EXCEPTION
   UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET
       FIRST_NAME = :NEW.FIRST_NAME,
       LAST_NAME = :NEW.LAST_NAME
   WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = :NEW_EMPLOYEE_ID
END;
```

Is there another way to mimic UPSERT  in Oracle10?

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is modify the DML in mid-stream from an INSERT to an UPDATE. The problem is that you cannot use a trigger to modify the same table that fired the trigger. All you can do is allow the original INSERT to proceed or raise an exception which your app would have to handle. To do what you're asking in the DB would require a stand-alone PL/SQL package that your application would call as an API _instead_ of submitting an INSERT. The package could do this check and then determine whether to submit an INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: **You said**: "I want to update when this exception would be thrown instead of attempting to insert the value. Should I use a trigger for this?". **I say**: no, you should change *batch job* so that it first checks data quality, and then decides whether to UPDATE or INSERT a row into the target table.

Comment: @Littlefoot The example I provided is not the real implementation, this job would run every morning and update thousands of rows. My concern is the overhead I am adding by checking manually if the issue exists through a SELECT query. I was hoping for a way where I could skip this query by utilizing Oracle's built in exceptions. I guess I could catch the exception then run the update query, but that is still adding overhead. It looks like I will be going with your suggestion of checking first then updating.

Comment: Triggers are *hidden overhead*. Sometimes I wish they never existed.

Comment: Seems to me that having a unique constraint on company_id would mean you could only ever have 1 employee for each company.  Your error has nothing to do with changing employee name.  In my opinion you should remove the trigger and have a look at MERGE which is an upsert.

Comment: "Oracle 10" means Oracle 10g release 2 from 2005?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I believe so